# How to deal with a distrustful manager

Tags: management

I've been working with this line manager for a bit over 6 months. He's my boss from the very beginning. He's a horrible micromanager, which is a problem in itself.

However here I would like to ask about a different problem.

He doesn't trust me.

For example, he asks me to create a report on something in an analytics software we use. I create it and send it to him. Then we meet someone specialised in the area of the report and my boss asks the person whether they know how to create the same report. I say: "Hey boss, I know how to create it. I actually sent it to you just yesterday!". The specialist asks how I created it, I describe it, the specialist confirms I've done that correctly and there's no other way to do that and they would do that exactly the same way.

3 days later I learn my boss actually went to another specialist and asked them to organise a meeting on how to create this report! I learn about that since he actually invits me to this meeting because he wants me to learn how to create this report. Basically he expects me to spend more than an hour listening how this report should be created. Of course I contacted this specialist too and asked them whether they have any other way to create the report apart from the way I'm using. The answer was "No! There's definitely no other way to create this report!".

This can last for months and include plenty of people.

I know this sounds as if one of us were totally crazy. I can tell you here, the report was 100% correct. When creating it for the first times I contacted several specialists, including those mentioned above, in order to be 100% sure I create it correctly (and yes, of course I mentioned to my boss that I had).

At the beginning I thought: he doesn't know me, I need to convince him I know what I'm doing. But it has been 6 months. And he does that with each and every topic, not just this one report. And I'm actually an experienced hire, not a recent graduate. Actually in many cases I could teach the people he contacts to confirm that I do something correctly how to do things, as I have more experience.

What ways are there to build trust or just deal with this situation better because for now my work is simply incredibly inefficient and I've been feeling extremely stressed out because of that?

Comment: Have you talked about this with any of your peers to see if this is something he is doing to you in particular or whether it's his typical MO?

Comment: How did your manager react when his chosen expert validated your approach?  Is there something about the approach that your manager is still not happy with given an "expert opinion" that backs up your own?

Comment: @Snow, he completely ignores other people's opinion. He normally continues searching for a person to tell him it could be done differently. Then he sometimes finds someone who says, using the example above, "actually there might also be another way to create this report" and he tells me to meet that person to learn how to create this report. The second way to create it is no better than the first way - it's exactly the same report. In the meantime I've wasted hours.

Comment: @motosubatsu, he has a clear preference for one of my colleagues so I don't think he treats us the same way. We have another colleague who is not treated like this, I think because there are no people who could verify his work - he's the only person with this area of expertise.

Comment: Most micromanagers don't trust their employees. It's why they micromanage.

Comment: You *could* try over at [IPS.SE](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/) but if it were me I'd explain that the reason he doesn't know and needs to call in a team of experts is: [drumroll] because he doesn't know. Ask if you can manage instead, if you're lucky he won't know, call in the team of experts, and they're sick of his fiddling.

Answer (score 5):

In this particular case, based on my experience and reading the tea leaves a bit, it sounds to me like your manager simply doesn't like you.  Therefore they don't trust you.

If you wish to stay put, *keep on meeting or exceeding your manager' expectations on the job*, **and** solicit feedback from them as to how you can do better.  Persistence is the key to improving the relationship by demonstrating you care.

**My gut feeling** on this is you should *either* find another department to work in or another company to work for.  You cannot **make** someone **like or trust you**.

Comment: I guess we are drinking the same tea...To add I can say jobs are like marriages and this was an arranged marriage and the bride dislikes you. You can try to give beautifull babies to your bride and hope that will bring the best of her but the process can backfire and make she hate you and even try to drown the babies

Answer (score 3):

It's time to dust off your resume and look for another job.

It looks very much as though your manager is helping you decide to leave by placing obstacles in the path of your productivity.

You've proved that you're competent enough, so look for another job where your competency can be valued.

You could try and do things his way, but you already know that it's the wrong approach and you'll only end up in a downward spiral of servitude and despondency.

Cut your losses and leave.